# how to make user select only one check box in a checkboxlist

Tags: asp.net, jquery

i have an check boxlist with (6 items under it). and i have an search button. if user  clicks Search button  it  gets  all the result. 
 i am  binding the  items   for checkboxlist   using database  in .cs  file

**condition1:**
but now if user  selects a checkbox[item1] its gets selected
 and he  tries to select an   2 checkbox[item2] then firstselected  checkbox[item1]  should be  unselected. only  checkbox[item2]  should  be selected

**condition 2:**
now if user  as  selected checkbox1 [item1] it  gets selected.  and now if user again clicks on checkboxi[item1]   then  it  should get deselected.

either  you can  provide  me the  solution in javascript or JQuery
 any help would  be great . looking forward  for an solution
 thank you

Comment: That's what radio buttons are for...

Comment: +1 Exactly thats What I am suggesting ! :)

Comment: I disagree. I've had to do something like this - the problem with radio buttons is that once you've checked one, there's no way to get back to a state where none of them are checked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I definitely agree with the consensus that radio buttons are the way to go for your described use-case, here is a little snipped of jquery that will cause checkboxes to behave like radio buttons.  You simply need to add a "groupname" attribute to your checkbox tag.

HTML:

```
<fieldset>
<legend>Group 1 - radio button behavior</legend>
<input type="checkbox" groupname="group1" value="1" /> Checkbox 1<br />
<input type="checkbox" groupname="group1" value="2" /> Checkbox 2<br />
<input type="checkbox" groupname="group1" value="3" /> Checkbox 3<br />
<input type="checkbox" groupname="group1" value="4" /> Checkbox 4<br />
<input type="checkbox" groupname="group1" value="5" /> Checkbox 5<br />
</fieldset>


<fieldset>    
<legend>Group 2 - radio button behavior</legend>
<input type="checkbox" groupname="group2" value="1" /> Checkbox 1<br />
<input type="checkbox" groupname="group2" value="2" /> Checkbox 2<br />
<input type="checkbox" groupname="group2" value="3" /> Checkbox 3<br />
<input type="checkbox" groupname="group2" value="4" /> Checkbox 4<br />
<input type="checkbox" groupname="group2" value="5" /> Checkbox 5<br />
</fieldset>

<fieldset>    
<legend>Group 3 normal checkbox behavior</legend>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" /> Checkbox 1<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="2" /> Checkbox 2<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="3" /> Checkbox 3<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="4" /> Checkbox 4<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="5" /> Checkbox 5<br />
</fieldset>
```

Javascript:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
        var groupName = $(this).attr('groupname');

            if (!groupName)
                return;

            var checked = $(this).is(':checked');

            $("input[groupname='" + groupName + "']:checked").each(function() {
                $(this).prop('checked', '');
            });

            if (checked)
                $(this).prop('checked', 'checked');
        });
    });
</script>
```

I'm sure there are opportunities to increase brevity and performance, but this should get you started.

Answer (score 10):

use Radio button. The only problem you will face is when you want to de-select the radio button. You can write in a javascript for 'onClick' of radio button. The onClick function can check whether radio button is selected, if it is not select it else deselect it.

Hope this helps. [See Example](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-21897.html)

RDJ

Comment: Another option for the "deselect" is to add an additional radio button that indicates nothing is selected (a none or nothing - the label to use depends upon the labels for the other buttons).  This eliminates the script and keeps with the traditional paradigm for radio buttons.

Comment: I just want to say that this solution only useful if you want your CheckBoxList to actually behave like a RadioButtonList.  A RadioButtonList does not allow you to take back that initial state of all items unchecked, whereas with a CheckBoxList you can toggle back and forth between unchecked and checked to return to all items unchecked, which is a possible scenario that one may want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use radio buttons, they are ideal for the purpose that you mentioned.

**Edit:**

If you necessarily want to use checkbox list then assign some logical ids to those checkboxes so that you can access them in JavaScript. 
On each onclick event of the checkboxes call the JavaScript and in the JavaScript loop through and see

- If any checkbox is checked other
  than the present clicked checkbox, 
  then make them unselected.
- If the present checkbox is already
  checked then just toggle it.

You can see if a checkbox is checked using `$("#checkboxId").is(":checked")` which returns true if a checkbox is checked.

Thanks

Comment: but  my Requirment is that  i need  to use check boxlist  what my client ask me

Comment: we usually solve this another way, we use a radiobutton list, and because the client asks for a checkbox list we replace the radiobuttons trough javascript libraries like niceforms and all, then you can use your own designed checkboxes while still have the functionality of a radiobuttonlist.

Answer (score 0):

**this was the  code that  helped  me  to solve this issue**

just add the script -

var objChkd;

function HandleOnCheck() 
{

var chkLst = document.getElementById('CheckBoxList1'); 
   if(objChkd && objChkd.checked)

```
      objChkd.checked=false;objChkd = event.srcElement;
```

}

and register the client event to the 'CheckBoxList1' at the Page_load as

CheckBoxList1.Attributes.Add("onclick","return HandleOnCheck()");

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at the [MutuallyExclusiveCheckBoxExtender](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/MutuallyExclusiveCheckBox/MutuallyExclusiveCheckBox.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

.aspx

```
<asp:CheckBoxList id="chkList" runat="server" RepeatLayout="Flow" />
```

.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    LimitCheckboxes('input[name*=chkList]', 3);
}



function LimitCheckboxes(control, max) {

    $(control).live('click', function () {

        //Count the Total Selection in CheckBoxList 
        var totCount = 1;
        $(this).siblings().each(function () {
            if ($(this).attr("checked")) { totCount++; }
        });

        //if number of selected item is greater than the max, dont select.
        if (totCount > max) { return false; }
        return true;
    });

}
```

PS: Make sure you use the RepeatLayout="Flow" to get rid of the annoying table format.

Answer (score 0):

My jQuery solution for this is coded as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    SetCheckboxListSingle('cblFaxTypes');
});

function SetCheckboxListSingle(cblId) {
    $('#' + cblId).find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
        $(this).bind('click', function () {
            var clickedCbxId = $(this).attr('id');
            $('#cblFaxTypes').find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
                if (clickedCbxId == $(this).attr('id'))
                return true;
               // do not use JQuery to uncheck the here because it breaks'defaultChecked'property
                // http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10357
                document.getElementById($(this).attr('id')).checked = false;

            });
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

we can do in  java script to get the solution for this.

For this first get the id of the checked item and go thorough the remaining items using loop then unchecked the remaining items

http://csharpektroncmssql.blogspot.com/2011/11/uncheck-check-box-if-another-check-box.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

**Code Behind (C#) :**

```
foreach (ListItem listItem in checkBoxList.Items)
{
    listItem.Attributes.Add("onclick", "makeSelection(this);");
}
```

**Java Script :**

```
function makeSelection(checkBox)
{
    var checkBoxList = checkBox;
    while (checkBoxList.parentElement.tagName.toLowerCase() != "table")
    {
        checkBoxList = checkBoxList.parentElement;
    }

    var aField = checkBoxList.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var bChecked = checkBox.checked;

    for (i = 0; i < aField.length; i++)
    {
        aField[i].checked = (aField[i].id == checkBox.id && bChecked);
    }
}
```