# Dynamic checkbox creation-need to restrict the number of checkboxes that can be selected

Tags: c#, .net, checkbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to make user select only one check box in a checkboxlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818102/how-to-make-user-select-only-one-check-box-in-a-checkboxlist)

I have created dynamic checkbox list reading the values from XML and populating it in checkbox list and

Checkboxes are getting created correctly, but I am bale to select select multiple checkboxes, I want that only one value can be selected, if I select 1 and then select 2 then 1 should get deselected. As of now all of the checkboxes can be selected.

Also, how do i capture the text value of the checkbox, as I need to pass it to a dictionary item.

Comment: Your desired behavior sounds a lot like normal behavior for a RadioButton. Is there a reason you chose CheckBoxes instead?

Comment: possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818102/how-to-make-user-select-only-one-check-box-in-a-checkboxlist

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use checkboxes then write an event handler so that oncheckboxselect you deselect all other checkbox's.